# Views and Facets without Search API

Tags: 7, views, search

Is there any way to use Facets for a Views' exposed filters without using Search API? This is for Drupal 7.

Comment: Short answer, no. You'll spend a ton of hours writing code only to wind up in the same spot. Why the aversion to using Search API? It's actually fantastic.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. I was using Search API but I'm having issues with it - number of results in the facets block is correct, but the View does not match it. I'll start a new question for this.